# How can I find the SourceLocation of a character after a SourceLocation in a Clang AST?

Tags: c++, clang, abstract-syntax-tree, lexer

I'm trying to use the Clang Lexer library to find the location of a token (specifically the left brace of a namespace declaration). My idea (since the NamespaceDecl doesn't have a method for it) was to find the location of the first left brace after the start of the namespace declaration. However, looking at the [Lexer API](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Lexer.html), I can't seem to find a short and simple way to do this while visiting an AST. Any suggestions/alternatives without having to do something drastic like reparse the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to find the brace. In my test, it works for both named and anonymous namespaces.

```
// Assuming ns_decl is pointer to the NamespaceDecl
// sm is reference to the SourceManager
... in addition to the usual headers:
#include "clang/Basic/TokenKinds.h"    // for clang::tok
#include "clang/Lex/Lexer.h"           // for Lexer
...
  clang::LangOptions lopt;
  bool skipNewLines = false;
  SourceLocation locToUse = ns_decl->isAnonymousNamespace() ?
    ns_decl->getLocStart() : ns_decl->getLocation();
  SourceLocation next_loc(
    clang::Lexer::findLocationAfterToken(
      locToUse,clang::tok::l_brace, sm,lopt,skipNewLines));
```

In a declaration like

```
namespace NOPQ  {
  void f(int){}
}

namespace
   ABCD
     {
  void g(float){}
}

namespace {
  void h(int){}
}
```

next_loc will correspond to line 1, col 18 for NOPQ; line 7, col 7 for ABCD; and line 11, col 12 for the anonymous ns.

Comment: Works wonderfully, thanks. There should probably be a bit more documentation surrounding getLocation(), because I just assumed it would be the same as getLocStart(). Also, as a followup question I (and others reading this question) will probably have sometime in the future: how can we do this generally? In other words, if I wanted to find the first position of a specific token after a location, how can I use the Lexer to do so?

Comment: For anyone else wondering, it works the exact same as the above.